# read from socket only when data available

Tags: java, sockets, datainputstream

I have a server app that while communicating with a client it reads input from the client and sends over to the client.
Currently i am using the `DataInputStream.read()` method for reading the data from the client, however this method is blocking the process. If no data is coming in the process just waits and does not proceed.
Here is my code for the class that created upon client connection:

```
public class Client implements Runnable{
private SSLSocket threadSocket;
private boolean running = true;
private DataOutputStream out;
private int nPort = 0;

//This constructor will be passed the socket
public ClientThread_control(SSLSocket socket, int port){
    threadSocket = socket;
    nPort = port;
}

public void run(){
    System.out.println("New connection at " + new Date() + "\n");
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (threadSocket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream (threadSocket.getOutputStream());
        while (running){
            // read input data
            byte[] one = new byte [1];
            in.read(one);
            int ln = in.available();
// do some stuff
            // parse in going message
            messageParsing(msg);

// do some stuff .... 

            // go to sleep
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        try {
            threadSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.\n");
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}}
```

When no data is available it does not get past the `in.read(one)` line.
My question is, can i some how now whether there is data or not, and if not then just skip this part and continue to the `do some stuff` part?
If there is no way, that means that the client should always send something in order for the server app continue running smoothly?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: check for async read

Comment: What should it do?

Comment: Either, you create for each connection new thread, which handles only read data - then it makes no sense to "do some stuff" without getting bytes from client, and it blocks only handlig one client, or, if you don't want to create a thread for each connection, I would use Selectors. It's pretty nice described here:http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html

Comment: @DanyLavrov This type of thing (like async socket or async file read) don't block for input. Check the link I put in my answer.

Comment: thank you both, i will dig into that.

Comment: @fairtrax i am creating a new thread for each connection, but those threads continue running until the client disconnects.

Comment: @DanyLavrov what are you dogin in the "do some staff" then? You only consumes a msg from client, or answer, right? You can also have 2 threads for connection - 1 for receiving a msg, one for consuming already arrived messages and creating an answer. I have never used the selectors, but they seem very useful, if you have huge amount of connections.

Comment: In the "do some stuff"  just send several messages to the client. However, the sending of those messages does not depend on the messages the client sends to the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
int ln = in.available();
```

In the circumstance you describe, `ln` will be zero, which you should test for and handle appropriately.

However this is a poor way to handle blocking I/O. The normal way is to dedicate a thread to reading the socket and handling whatever arrives on it.

If you don't want that, you should be using non-blocking NIO, or asynchronous I/O.